# Select one item from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So, I wanna select item per item from this array **["A185","A740","A540"]** 
Like for example I wanna select

> $cie[0] = **A185** or **A740**
>
> with something like **$cie[0] = A185**

This is my code so far, since I fetch that code from a row in a MySQL table.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($resul)) {
    $cie10 = array($row["cie"]);
}


    $cie = ["A185","A740"];

    $values = array_count_values($cie);

    $top = array_slice($values, 0, 1);
    print_r($top);
```

What I get:
Array ( [["A185","A740","A540"]] => 1 )

It just won't work.

Comment: Not clear enough what you want to achieve.

Comment: everytime you want 0 index key ?

Comment: You already got it? `$cie[0]`. Given that `$cie` is your array of items

Comment: Yeah it is, but it wont work. This is the result: Array ( [["A185","A740"]] => 1 )

Comment: @Syer-J you want to save 1 value in ["A185","A740"] this

Comment: what is your expected output update it, stuff really not enough and poor to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem. You are looking for this:-

```
$Fullarray = ["A185","A740","A540"];
$cie = array_slice($Fullarray,0,2);
foreach ($cie as $name) {
   $d[] = '"' . $name . '"';
}
$implodekeys = "[".implode(',',$d)."]";
$newarray[$implodekeys] =1;
echo "<pre>"; print_r($newarray);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work either. I'll update the question with more code.

Comment: what you mean by doesn't work have you tried or gusseing share full info

Comment: I did, and still not working. What I get -> Array
(
 [["A185","A740"]] => 1
)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sure you are looking to display the data that is in the array variable

```
$var = ["A185","A740","A540"]; // Asume as you stored the values in the array called var

foreach($var as $x){
 print_r($x);
 echo "<br/>";
}
```

EDIT: Highlighted the code

Comment: Yep, I just wanna fetch the first 2 results. Since the array could hold more values. Your code gives this -> ["A185","A740"]. What I need it's to fetch just A185, without the "" or the comma.

Comment: So you can use this code to fetch only one data from the array. $var = ["A185","A740","A540"];
echo $var[2];